# htaccess URL Text Removal In Betwee Slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

REAL URL: - http://www.bankifscfinder.com/branch_list.html?p_num=297&&&ser_bankname=147

Duplicate URL: - http://www.bankifscfinder.com/aaa/branch_list.html?p_num=297&&&ser_bankname=147

I want to redirect url to REAL url if user enter any text in like "aaa" or anything else. Numbers in url is CMS provided.

Comment: Do you have any code samples?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

where 404.php is the file name and placed at root. You can put full path over here.